# How to identify whether or not std::unordered_map has experienced hash collisions?

Tags: c++, stl, collision, unordered-map, hash-collision

How to identify whether or not the keys in a `std::unordered_map` have experienced hash collisions?

That is, how to identify if any collision chaining is present?

Comment: I suspect you want to enforce some policy if it is the case, then ask the unordered_map to enforce it don't try to force it from client code. Check if max_load_factor member function solves the underling question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [bucket interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Bucket_interface) and its `bucket_size` method.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
bool has_collision = false;

for(size_t bucket = 0; bucket < map.bucket_count(); bucket++) {
    if(map.bucket_size(bucket) > 1) {
        has_collision = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If two elements happens to be in the same bucket it does not mean that there was a hash collision.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot -- sure it does; that's the definition of a collision.

Comment: a simple `if (map.bucket_count() < map.size())` can be done to quickly check if there are any collisions to avoid the for loop in many cases

Comment: @phuclv there can be empty buckets, so a total count check won't suffice.