# How to evaluate custom hash function?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashmap, associative-array, hash-collision

I have a `Dictionary` with a custom hashing function. I want to test the hash function, because even though it returns *different hash* results for my test values, ***some of them may still map to the same bucket due to the [modulo `%` operation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,304)***. So how to check if there are collisions in C# `Dictionary` with custom hash function and improve that function?

This is a ***development test*** to fine-tune the hash function and **won't go into production** so no worries about the changes in internal implementation in other versions!!!

In C++ it's possible to [get the map's bucket size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46137811/995714) to check the collision status but I couldn't find a way to do that in C#. How can I know if `Dictionary` has been collided?

Comment: I think it's an implementation detail. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the hash code (`GetHashCode()`)?

Comment: Do you care if it is built into the library?  The hash if the first check of the key to do a lookup in log2(N) time.  After the hash is used a second check is done if there are duplicate hash values by comparing the dictionary key against the has key to get unique key value.

Comment: @Sweeper just curious, and it's also useful to quickly check some custom hashing functions

Comment: @mjwills of course I know how to use `GetHashCode()` because I'm implementing it myself for my class. However different hashes doesn't mean that collision has not occured because internally the dictionary may use some modulo operation, which maps different hashes to the same bucket

Comment: Fair enough. When people talk about collisions they are often talking about equal hash codes - so just wanted to confirm what you were actually looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can get internal buckets in the following way:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("a", 8);
dictionary.Add("b", 1);
var buckets = dictionary.GetType().GetField("_buckets", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
              .GetValue(dictionary); // use "buckets" for 4.x
```

Comment: `dictionary.GetType().GetField("_buckets", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)` returns `null`

Comment: I use .net core. For .NET 4.x you must changed _buckets to buckets

Comment: @CihanYakar while this technically answers OPs question, it's not good practice.  You're intentionally breaking encapsulation.  If the internal implementation details change for any reason, your program stops working.

Comment: Yes! @just.another.programmer; any changes can do it. I agree with you. But for checking something it seems be ok. But it is not a reliable code ofcourse. Internal implementation can change in the next version.

Comment: @CihanYakar you yourself already pointed at the implementation changed in a way that would have broken this code between .NET 4.x and .NET Core.  There's a reason we use access modifiers to enforce encapsulation!  Have a look at my answer for a way to solve the problem without breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Yes indeed! I just wanted to show how to access internal items.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off creating a custom `Dictionary` implementation that changes the `Add` and `Remove` methods to check for hash collisions based on the computer `GetHashCode` of the elements.  You can compose with a "real" `Dictionary` internally to do the real work of storing the elements.

Here's a sample version.  You could optimize the `Add` and `Remove` methods depending on the type of hashes your expecting.

```
public class CollisionDetectingDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> InternalDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    private readonly List<int> HashCodesInDictionary = new List<int>();

    public event Action<int, TKey, IEnumerable<TKey>> HashCollision; 

    public TValue this[TKey key] { get => InternalDictionary[key]; set => InternalDictionary[key] = value; }
    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => InternalDictionary.Keys;
    public ICollection<TValue> Values => InternalDictionary.Values;
    public int Count => InternalDictionary.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var hashCode = item.Key.GetHashCode();
        if (HashCodesInDictionary.Contains(hashCode))
        {
            var collisions = GetKeysByHashCode(hashCode);
            HashCollision?.Invoke(hashCode, item.Key, collisions);
        }

        Add(item);
    }

    private IEnumerable<TKey> GetKeysByHashCode(int hashCode)
    {
        foreach (var key in Keys)
        {
            if(key.GetHashCode() == hashCode)
            {
                yield return key;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        InternalDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return InternalDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return InternalDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((IDictionary<TKey,TValue>)InternalDictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        var hashCode = key.GetHashCode();
        if(GetKeysByHashCode(hashCode).Count() == 1)
        {
            HashCodesInDictionary.Remove(hashCode);
        }

        return InternalDictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return Remove(item.Key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return InternalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return InternalDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also write this methodology like : `var hasCollision = dictionary.Keys.GroupBy(k => k.GetHashCode()).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);`

Comment: @CihanYakar yes, but that's a trade-off in efficiency.  That requires calculating the hash code of the entire dictionary contents every time you add an item.  For a large dictionary, you'll take a performance hit by doing that.  In my implementation there's a performance hit on remove.  Like I said, depending on the expected use of the dictionary will depend how you code the implementation.

Comment: Of course, it depends on purpose. I am asking just for clarifying and fun :).  If it will check only after the dictionary filled up, LINQ solution will be better (sake of simplicity), but if the user wants to get an immediate response, your solution is good. And both solutions won't work with a custom comparer.